# get RGB pixel values from uint8 c++

Tags: c++, image-processing

I create a c# function that moves BitmapFrame picture to  byte[] (using copypixels). Then I paste this buffer into c++ dll where it is uint8*. There is a structure in cpp

```
typedef struct  
{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
} pixel;
```

Is it possible to organize a loop for this uint8* buffer to get pixel-by pixel (for example by x y - height and width of image(this data I have too))?
 something  like

```
for(i=0; i< height;i++)
{
for(j=0; j <width;j++)
{
   SomeWorkWithPixelsfromUint8(i,j) //???
}
}
```

Where SomeWorkWithPixelsfromUint8(i,j) could operate RGB structure

So simple uint8 -> getPixel(x,y)  ????

Comment: what library are you working with?

Comment: No library. I try to write my own =) If you ask about c++ dll - this is my code too. I am trying to connect this three entitys - RGB + pixel(that has RGB )+ buffer of pixels

Comment: Is a single `uint8` representing the whole pixel, or the red, green and blue components each are `uint8`?

Comment: well how are you packing the rgb value?

Comment: Blagovest Buyukliev - no this is for ALL pixels and stride of pic Daniel A. White -  pixel operations(int x, int y, uint8 inputBuffer){    uint8 buffer = inputBuffer;
 Point p;
 p.x = x;
 p.y = y;
 Rect rec;
 rec.xBottomLeft = 0.f;
 rec.yBottomLeft = 0.f;
 rec.width = buffer->width;
 rec.height = buffer->height;
}

Comment: Are you the joker that killed my cat?

Comment: ) I love cats) I haved a BIG Siberian cat - Smoky. sadly it dead many years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your picture data have a layout like this

- Pixels are scanlines per scanlines, left to right
- One pixel is packed as RGB, or eventually RGBA
- You use *pixelSize* bytes per pixel (might be 3, might be 4 if you alpha channel)

---

```
uint8_t* picData = ...;

uint8_t* pixel = picData;
for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
  for(int j = 0; j < width; ++j, pixel += pixelSize) {
       float r = pixel[0];
       float g = pixel[1];
       float b = pixel[2];
       // Do something with r, g, b
  }
}
```

---